# Is there any trick to memorize the linux command args?

Tags: linux

the command args and options are very boring and hard to keep in mind.Is any trick to memorize them?

Comment: What "linux command" are you referring to?

Comment: linux shell command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No real tricks, just another muscle memory practice. However there are a few tricks to make it faster.

This makes a good background for the new programmer. 
http://ss64.com/bash/

Also google how to make bash aliases. They allow you to pick shortcuts for whatever commands you want. But also spend some time to read the docs, you will soon see how powerful they can be.

Helpful commands to know!
$ help
Also if you forget what a command does just read its man page!
$ man foo
foo being the command you want to look up.